# Not able to send email using log4j SMTP Appender. Getting "SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.1 Authentication required"

Tags: java, email, logging, log4j

Please see below my log4j.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="email" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
        <param name="BufferSize" value="1" /> 
        <param name="SMTPHost" value="smtp.mail.yahoo.com" />
        <param name="SMTPPort" value="587" />
        <param name="SMTPUsername" value="email@yahoo.in" /> 
        <param name="SMTPPassword" value="password" /> 
        <param name="From" value="email@yahoo.in" />
        <param name="To" value="email@gmail.com" />
        <param name="Subject" value="Error Log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[${name}] - %d{ISO8601} - %X{login} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="error" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="fatal" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="email" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

On execution of this program, I am getting below error message:

```
log4j:ERROR Error occured while sending e-mail notification.
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.1 Authentication required
```

Any help is highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading javax.mail to 1.4.7 worked for me.

```
compile('javax.mail:mail:1.4.7')
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following in your smtp appender configuration and change port to 465 with log4j version 1.2.17

```
<param name="SMTPProtocol" value="smtps" />
```

Comment: Thanks Shi for the response. But I am getting the same error after adding your suggested configuration.

Comment: log4j:ERROR Error occured while sending e-mail notification.
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.1 Authentication required

 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1609)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1117)

Comment: Some improvement. But find below exception.

Comment: log4j:ERROR Error occured while sending e-mail notification.
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Comment: Check with port 465

Comment: I am sorry, but another exception.

Comment: log4j:ERROR Error occured while sending e-mail notification.
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)

Comment: Can you check again with <param name="TLS" value="true" /> on both port?

Comment: With port 465:  log4j:ERROR Error occured while sending e-mail notification.
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)

Comment: With port 587:    log4j:ERROR Error occured while sending e-mail notification.
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)

Comment: I'm sorry :-(, can you please use and check with both the parameters given in answer.

Comment: It worked for me with port 465 and SMTPProtocol smtps. I have updated my answer. hope it will work for you too. thanks.

Comment: Make sure your log4j version is 1.2.16 or 1.2.17, otherwise SMTP Protocol property will not work. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Shi, Thanks for your help. But I am still getting below error. I even using required libraries as you suggested.

Comment: log4j:ERROR Error occured while sending e-mail notification.
javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.SocketException: Connection reset